# Creating a simple calculator using strings in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn Java. My current assignment is to build a simple four function calculator..... this would be easy given if/else and/ or switch statements, but I'm supposed to build this using methods.
The original input has to be put in as a single string, so, in my mind, I'm going to have to take the single string and create substrings, then somehow convert these substrings into double values, while deleting whatever whitespace could possibly be between characters. My current idea is to somehow identify the "+,-,*, or /" within the string and divide into substrings before and after these values, using the appropriate defined method for whichever operator to do the calculations....
The problem is that I can't see a good way to divide these up into substrings or how to convert the  numbers involved into double values. Anyone got any advice for me? Keep in mind, what we have gone through is pretty limited and I feel like I'm missing something REALLY simple out there.

Comment: Do you need to honor order of operations?

Answer (score 1):

You can split a string based on a particular character using `str.split("\\+")`, for example. You can convert the split pieces of the string to doubles by using `Double.parseDouble(str);`

Comment: Added escape characters for +